# Get Firebase Collection and loop through them

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i am getting an object from firebase collection. Then I am setting them in a variable and using for loop to iterate over them. But in the view I can not see anything. I have tried to change the variable type to array but still I cant see anything.

```
public allPets : any;

getPetsForCurrentUser(){
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) =>{
      if(user){
          this.afs.collection('pets', ref => ref.where('OwnerID', '==', user.uid)).get().toPromise()
          .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
              let pets = doc.data();
              pets.id = doc.id;
              this.allPets = doc.data()
              console.log(this.allPets);
            });
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }else {
        console.log("No user logged in");
      }
    });
  }
```

Component :

```
<div class="single-pet-list" *ngFor="let pet of allPets">
<p>{{ pet.OwnerName }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you getting here `console.log(this.allPets);`?

Comment: I am getting an object with key value pairs

Comment: Don't you need a line of code to tell the UI to refresh or display itself? I don't think this assignment is going to do that for you automatically: `this.allPets = doc.data()`

Comment: I think the doc.data() is returning an object where as this.allPets is any type, is it creating the problem

Comment: @RahulKundu where are u calling this method? inside ngOnInt?

Comment: Yes from oninit